# How to make available libgthread-2.0.so.0 inside Docker Container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to load JNI native library inside spring boot application,It loads fine when I run it from eclipse by providing `-Djava.library.path={path_to_mynativelib}`,as VM argument ,but when I try to run application using **docker-compose** file ,and providing same VM arguments as `JAVA_OPTS: "-Djava.library.path={path_nativelib_inside_docker_container}"` ,after running application ,it throws exception of not loading i.e `Error loading shared library libgthread-2.0.so.0: No such file or directory` ,after debugging I found that `libgthread-2.0.so.0` is available in my host linux machine at path `/usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0` that why in eclipse it does not throw any exception,how I can load this lib inside docker container

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install `libglib2.0-0` inside your Docker container. Once you have it there, make sure it's on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Note that your `JNI` library (that is probably linked to `gthread`) has to be able to see the library during runtime.